# Vuejs 3 with node 17 issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this issue with my app with start it seems to be that every single programmer in the global face this issue.
any one find the solution for that???
this is the issue:

```
rror: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /Users/mj/Documents/Deploy/Github/Projs/Front/Web/Test/VueTest/hello-world/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I searched a lot here in StackOverflow and in Github even in Vuejs documentation but there is no solution for that.
It's show up as soon as I run the app with the:

```
npm run serve
```

command

Comment: Odd Node versions aren't for production. Do not use them, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @EstusFlask I didn't know this. Is this odd/even version thing documented some where?

Comment: It's a common knowledge, similar to some other opensource. Only even ones are LTS, i.e.widely supported, https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/. Install the recommended one, https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work, adding a `--openssl-legacy-provider` flag.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6770#issuecomment-982663524